# Возможно ли упростить выборку из БД?

Tags: mysql

Суть проблемы в том что производится проверка наличия записей в базе в виде:

```
"SELECT * FROM `таблица` WHERE `свойство1` = '%s' AND `свойство2` = '%s'"
```

Но позиций которые проверяются десяток тысяч и делается это очень часто, и соответственно делаются десятки тысяч запросов. Можно ли как-то упростить систему?

В случае отсутствия совпадений - новая запись добавляется в базу.

Comment: сделать индекс?

Comment: *В случае отсутствия совпадений - новая запись добавляется в базу.* А в случае присутствия? А для комбинации `(свойство1, свойство2)` возможно наличие дубликатов, или эта пара должна быть уникальна?

Comment: Десяток тысяч записей достаточно маленькое значение, чтобы база справлялась с запросом за пару миллисекунд при наличии индекса. Это сотня запросов в секунду и тысячи в минуту. У вас точно такая нагрузка на сервер? А еще в некоторых случаях можно объединить проверку со вставкой.

Comment: @Akina пара должна быть уникальна

Comment: @AlexKrass база на сервере, проверка с десктопов производится, собственно время на это тратится. При запуске на сервере все быстрее.  Как раз про индекс подсказали. Изучаю тему.

Comment: *пара должна быть уникальна* Тогда по ней ОБЯЗАН существовать уникальный индекс. Тогда запросы должны просто летать. А если их идёт поток - то таблица и индекс будут постоянно присутствовать в кэше, в этих условиях и тысяча запросов в секунду должна обрабатываться без проблем - если что и будет тормозить процесс, так это скорее будет сеть, а не сервер.

Comment: @AntonKalenik, чтобы еще снизить сетевую составляющую и не гнать туда-судя проверку и вставку, можно воспользоваться условием на вставку `insert into ... select ... where not exists`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table

Comment: @AlexKrass В MySQL? да при наличии уникального индекса? гораздо разумнее `INSERT .. ODKU`. Или даже (для данной задачи) `INSERT IGNORE`.

Comment: @Akina, при наличии уникального индекса да, ваш вариант предпочтительней. По ссылке рассматриваются разные варианты и по дубликату вопроса еще и объясняются. Итоговый все равно надо тестировать на месте. Но всяко лучше, чем гонять данные лишний раз по сети.